# How to join one or more azure tables storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have to join two or more azure storage tables and fetch the data of two azure storage tables by joining them

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to do server-side joins with tables in Azure Tables as you would do with relational database tables.

What you would need to do is fetch the data from your tables separately and then do the join on the client side by writing some custom code.